# Not having to list all possibilities with bools and template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, boolean

(See edit at the end for clarification)

I'm trying to use bool's as template parameters. I'd like to be able to write something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<bool a, bool b>
void foo() {
    printf("%d %d\n", (int)a, (int)b);   
}

int main()
{
    int c = 2 ;
    c += 2 % 4 - 3 + 1 ;
    bool a = c % 2 == 0 ;
    bool b = c % 2 == 1 ;
    foo<a, b>();
}
```

but, as expected, I have a

> 16:9: error: the value of 'a' is not usable in a constant expression
>   14:10: note: 'bool a' is not const

Of course I could do something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<bool a, bool b>
void foo() {
    printf("%d %d\n", (int)a, (int)b);   
}

int main()
{
    int c = 2 ;
    c += 2 % 4 - 3 + 1 ;
    bool a = c % 2 == 0 ;
    bool b = c % 2 == 1 ;
    if(a) {
        if(b) {
            foo<true,true>();
        } else {
            foo<true,false>();
        }
    } else {
        if(b) {
            foo<false,true>();
        } else {
            foo<false,false>();
        }
    }
}
```

but it's a bit nasty. Since a and b are bools, is there any way to not have to explicitly list all possibilities ? Could the compiler figure that out by himself ?

EDIT: to clarify: I understand templates are compile time "variables". My question is wether the compiler could automatically generate all the functions, based on the fact that a bool is either true/false (so it's a limite "range" of values, which is what you need to use templates in some sense), and then add the required "plumbing" so that the right function is choosen at runtime.

Thanks,

Comment: Templates are decided at compile-time, but you're trying to choose the implementation at run-time. As such, templates is probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: I agree. My though was that, since it's a bool (either true or false and nothing else), maybe the compiler could automatically generate the required functions based on the possibilities.

Comment: I understand it might be a bit too much to ask from the compiler though :-)

Comment: It's not really that it can't generate the functions---the problem is that you can't choose the right function as that is decided at runtime. You're probably better off doing some `if`/`else` statements in the `foo` function.

Comment: Well conceptually, I guess it could do the "plumbing" (adding the if/else's) by himself. Not saying it's easy or whatever though, just wondering if something like that exists. Cause if you have 10 bools as template argument (a bit extreme I agree), would be nice to let the compiler generate and correctly choose the function, amongst the 2^10, automatically :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template arguments are evaluated at compile time. Now consider this modification of your example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<bool a, bool b>
void foo() {
    printf("%d %d\n", (int)a, (int)b);   
}

int main()
{
    int c = 2 ;

    std::cin >> c;        

    bool a = c % 2 == 0 ;
    bool b = c % 2 == 1 ;
    foo<a, b>();
}
```

Here, there is no way how to evaluate at compile time. Unfortunatelly the compiler cannot distinguish between these two examples.

Compiler cannot generate all the functions itself (if you had ints, would you want it to generate 2**32-1 functions?) unless you ask for specific ones:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

template <bool a, bool b>
void func() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << a << " " << std::boolalpha << b << std::endl;
}

std::map<bool, std::map<bool, std::function<void ()>>> dispatcher;

template <bool a, bool b>
void register_dispatcher() {
    dispatcher[a][b] = func<a,b>;
}

int main() {
    register_dispatcher<false, false>();
    register_dispatcher<false, true>();
    register_dispatcher<true, false>();
    register_dispatcher<true, true>();

    bool a, b;
    a = false;
    b = true;

    dispatcher[a][b](); 
    // for clarity I don't handle nonexistent keys

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the code requires C++11.

Now you may want 10 bool arguments and generate each of them. Beware, that's 1024 functions. Not that much, but be careful. Let's do it with 3:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

template <bool a, bool b, bool c>
void func() {
    std::cout 
        << std::boolalpha << a << " " 
        << std::boolalpha << b << " "
        << std::boolalpha << c << " "
        << std::endl;
}

std::map<bool, std::map<bool, std::map<bool, std::function<void ()>>>> dispatcher;

template <bool a, bool b, bool c>
void register_dispatcher() {
    dispatcher[a][b][c] = func<a,b, c>;
}

template <bool a, bool b>
void register_dispatcher_2() {
    register_dispatcher<a, b, true>();
    register_dispatcher<a, b, false>();
}

template <bool a>
void register_dispatcher_1() {
    register_dispatcher_2<a, true>();
    register_dispatcher_2<a, false>();
}

void register_dispatcher_0() {
    register_dispatcher_1<true>();
    register_dispatcher_1<false>();
}

int main() {
    register_dispatcher_0();

    bool a, b, c;
    a = false;
    b = true;
    c = true;

    dispatcher[a][b][c]();

    return 0;
}
```

The code generates one argument at a time. It would start being worth it at some 7 or 8 arguments, or when you start mixing in ints.

Comment: I understand, but as was thinking about the compiler generating all the possible values (it's a bool so it's limited) and then choosing the right function at runtime (see edit in question).

Comment: @leo: answer extended

Comment: I almost got it to scale up, but I have run out of time. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9a417ac8d22fbb1

Comment: @MooingDuck: Something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b69eb80a47aa70c9).

Comment: @Jarod42: I considered `index_sequence`, but avoided it because it scales poorly with 8+ params. But props for getting a working version!

Comment: @MooingDuck: I tried first to fix your version (you mixed type and value), but reached template recursion limit. Not sure what you mean about scaling (`index_sequence` got 128 values in given version).

Answer (score 1):

By adding some `const`/`constexpr`, you may do

```
constexpr int c_ini = 2 ;
constexpr int c = c_ini + 2 % 4 - 3 + 1 ;
constexpr bool a = c % 2 == 0 ;
constexpr bool b = c % 2 == 1 ;
foo<a, b>();
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Ez86Ui)